# Returning multiple values from Db Entities (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have 2 class controllers - House and Apartment, and a Get method in apartments class that returns apartments that are in the house with the given id, here is the route:

```
[Route("api/house/{houseId}/apartments")]
```

I have this code and it returns apartment(single). The question is, how to make this work with more than 1 return result? Current code gives error if there are multiple apartments to return.

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Apartment))]
public IHttpActionResult GetApartments(Guid houseId)
{
    Apartment apartment = db.Apartments.SingleOrDefault(user => user.HouseId == houseId);
    if (apartment == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(apartment);
}
```

Comment: "Current code gives error" what error? I'm pretty sure your problem is using a `Single` result when you want all results. Use `.db.Apartments.Where(user => user.HouseId == houseId).ToList()` instead

Comment: The error code is: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains more than one element'"

Answer (score 1):

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Apartment[]))]
public IHttpActionResult GetApartments(Guid houseId)
{
    var apartments = db.Apartments.Where(user => user.HouseId == houseId).ToList();
    if (!apartments.Any())
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(apartments);
}
```

Use [`ToList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of `SingleOrDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Apartment apartment = db.Apartments.FirstOrDefault(user => user.HouseId == houseId);
```

Gives the first or default result.

```
Apartment apartment = db.Apartments.First(user => user.HouseId == houseId);
```

Gives the first or null result (if nothing is found).

```
Apartment apartment = new Apartment();
var apts = db.Apartments.Where(user => user.HouseId == houseId).toList();
if (apts.Any()) apartment = apts[0];
```

Get the first result of the list.